# Is it a bad idea to use a single Redis instance for both session and backend caching in Magento?

Tags: session, magento, caching, redis, magento-1.9

For Magento (v1.9 or lower), is okay to use a single Redis instance for both session and backend caching? Is there any extra configuration required?

Comment: FYI, duplicate question posted on Magento StackExchange (context is M2, not M1.9, but the same answers apply): https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196876/why-separate-redis-instances-for-sessions-and-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research, it seems like using the same instance for both session and backend cache is easy to do with the only potential problem being running out of space (not an issue if you're on AWS using ElastiCache).

Different port numbers are also not necessary. You just need to specify different "database numbers". The following is an example config:

```
  <cache>
    <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
    <backend_options>
      <server>$REDIS_CACHE</server>
      <port>6379</port>
      <persistent></persistent>
      <database>1</database> <!-- DIFFERENT DB NUMBER -->
      <password></password>
      <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
      <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
      <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
      <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
      <compress_data>1</compress_data>
      <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
      <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
      <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
      <use_lua>0</use_lua>
    </backend_options>
  </cache>
  <session_save>db</session_save>
  <redis_session>
    <host>$REDIS_CACHE</host>
    <port>6379</port>
    <password></password>
    <timeout>2.5</timeout>
    <persistent></persistent>
    <db>2</db> <!-- DIFFERENT DB NUMBER -->
    <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
    <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
    <log_level>1</log_level>
    <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
    <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
    <fail_after>10</fail_after>
    <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
    <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>
    <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
    <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
    <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
    <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
    <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
  </redis_session>
```

Comment: Note that AWS ElastiCache does not avoid the issue of running out of space. You have a fixed node capacity, and if you run out of memory entries will be evicted just like on self-hosted Redis instance. All ElastiCache helps in this regard is simplifying scaling out if you need it, but it's still a manual action (as of now there is no true autoscaling ability).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single instance, but you'd still use separate data stores for each of them, e.g. 6379 and 6380 but on the same Redis server.

There's no extra configuration required over having separate instances from the Magento side.

Comment: Apparently I asked a poor question. But it won't let me delete it since you answered :/

Comment: It's borderline, yeah. I tried to delete my answer but can't because you've accepted it :-)

Comment: It's all good. I'm not going to delete the question anymore. I answered my own question after doing more research with a pretty good answer, if you ask me. I think this is a useful Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend seperate instances.
Advantages over single instance with same db, or even different dbs

1. **Space and configuration control** : You would not want to logout a user because your caching is taking too much redis space. A redis object which stores some page cache might cause a session data key to get evicted, not good.
2. **Key name spacing control** : Your keys would be seperated based on concern, and you can use things like flushing to clear all of your cache, or to logout your users on some major change. Instead of having to delete keys by pattern.